# how does the view page source changes in a nextJS app when we route from one page to another

Tags: next.js, vercel

I had a doubt related to NextJS since a long time. Tried reading multiple docs but it was of no use.

Might be u guys can help me here.

So it goes like this:

1. I have a nextJS app deployed on production and it uses SSR (getServerSideprops).There is no SSG,ISR.Only SSR and CSR. SSR is used to get some html from the server so that google crawlers can get some content to read.
2. suppose i hit this url in my browser: [www.abc.com/proddetail/product1.html](http://www.abc.com/proddetail/product1.html)

It will enter my nextJS app inside pages/proddetail/[prodinfo] folder where I am hitting my API inside getserversideprops and getting the response at server end. At server end my html is rendered and is sent to the client. And in the client side, we know that it gets hydrated and my page is visible.

Now one more thing to keep in mind: whatever html is sent by the nextJS server can also be seen in the view page source

3. now on my client side i have many anchor tags(using Link component) that routes me to other pages (SPA implementation.)

Lets suppose I am going to click on a URL: [www.abc.com/proddetail/product2.html](http://www.abc.com/proddetail/product2.html)

Now what nextJS is doing is this:

When I click on product2.html a request goes in my network tab as [www.abc.com/_next/data/67/proddetail/product2.html.json](http://www.abc.com/_next/data/67/proddetail/product2.html.json) [NextJS internally hits this kind of json request]

From the server, I am getting the API data and maybe in the frontend the UI is changed using the virtual DOM.

My main question is my View page source also gets changed. But how is it possible? Because View page source contains the html that is sent by the server.

On clicking product2.html anchor tag, we r only getting the data corresponding to this new url and not the html from the nextJS server.

The view page source should not have changed and it should be same as that of product1.html.

This is making me crazy that how NextJS also able to change the view page source when we move from one route to another as in network tab u wont get the html returned from the server for the new route

My expectation is that view page source contains the content(html/css/js) that is returned by the server and this content is specially read by google crawlers to index my pages.

But in NextJS how is the view page source changing automatically when we route to different pages?
Because while clicking on a different route, I can only see a request of a json file to the server and from the server I am only getting the data from the server and not the rendered html.